# Why recieveValue block is called twice?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine


final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init() {
        $text
            .sink { completion in

            } receiveValue: { text in
                print("Text \(text)")
            }.store(in: &cancellables)

    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject private var vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Title", text: $vm.text)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

What I have noticed, if I type one letter, i receive two values.
So at first it will just say `Text`. And if I type one letter, say letter A, output will look like this:

```
Text A

Text A
```

In some cases I saw it prints same value even more than two times.

I know I can use `removeDuplicates` but why is this actually happening?

Comment: I think its not the issue with sink closure, if you check didSet for `text` it also gets called twice, looks like an issue with the SwiftUI text field

Comment: @TejaNandamuri  Thanks... Well yeah, kind of it answers.. Seems like a bug.

Comment: There's no specification that says, that the binding will only be written by TextField when the value actually is different. There might be some complexity under the hood in TextField that causes this and I agree that one could fix it within TextField - but the current behaviour is _not_ invalid. Just be defensive in your code.

Comment: I am more concerned about your approach to observe changes of the published property `text` in your model via adding a subscriber. I consider this an anti-pattern. It's also not a "ViewModel" at all according the original specification of MVVM. There, you cannot have "two-way bindings".  In MVVM, views render a const value and send _commands_ to the model. They never change their rendered value themselves. The above approach makes it easy to  introduce subtle bugs in your logic when you observe and handle a couple more of those properties this way using subscriptions.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Well I agree that I don't need really two way binding for that `TextField`. But what would be the way to make one-way communication and that I can still observe changes eg. when text is empty, that I disable button (from viewModel) and vice-versa but that I can't accidentally set text of `TextField` from view model? If I understood good your point?

Comment: In order to employ a uni-directional and event driven approach: You still need a Binding to interface with a TextField. But a Binding has a getter and a setter.  What you can do is define a Binding in the _body_ of a view, where the getter is a function which reads from model and the setter is a function which sends a "command"  (with a parameter String) to the model. A "command" could be a case of an Enum "Event" which comprises all commands, where you have the case: `case edit(String)`.  Your model receives all commands via `send(_ event: Event)`, where it updates the published properties.

Comment: I have to add, that the behaviour of `TextField` changed in iOS 17.x in a way that makes it incompatible to utilise an unidirectional approach (or any approach which attempts to change the input): once one initialised the TextField, it starts showing the string initially available through the binding. But when editing, it never reads this binding anymore. That is, one cannot change the string content of a TextField via the binding as long as it is editing. This is in contrast to TextField in the iOS versions 16 and before, where one could set the binding, and TextField would render it.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Ok   I see, thanks.. Will try that one with binding in a body...

Comment: Whirlwind, if you are interested, I have a small demo. Since it's off topic for your question, I put it into a private gist:  https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/b42db439c973c12ece95f30b2fc15ac1

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Oh, thank you for the effort. That code is quite tidy and neat by the way! I was looking at it, but I must admit, I've never tried that kind of architecture before (state machine with effects / side effects). Nevertheless, I will try to implement one of my own screens using your example, so I can compare things a bit..

Answer (score -2):

Lots of mistakes:

1. In SwiftUI the `View` struct hierarchy is the view model already don't try to use classes or you'll run into major issues.
2. In a Combine `ObservableObject` you shouldn't use `sink` or `cancellables`, instead use `.assign` to complete the pipeline to an `@Published`. That way the lifetime is correct, i.e. the pipeline will be cancelled and tore down when the object deinits, which is what `@StateObject` does. This can be used for a fetcher type object but not for view data.
3. `@StateObject` is for when you need a reference type in a `@State`, e.g. for a delegate or an async Combine pipeline, don't try to use them to make view models because that is the job of the `View` struct. If you upgrade to async/await and the `.task` modifier you don't need `@StateObject` anymore.

Your code fixed looks like this:

```
struct Content {
    var text = ""
    /// other related vars

   // other testable funcs
   mutating func reset() {
       text = ""
   }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var content = Content()

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Title", text: $content.text)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Comment: None of this answers the legitimate original question of why `Text A` is printed more than once.

Comment: Because of all the mistakes I pointed out!

Comment: @malhal Thanks, yeah. `assign(to)` seems more reasonable.